# Where do players inside vents appear on the admin table?

Tags: among-us

When a player uses a vent, it's often easy to tell on the admin table. For example, if you have 2 in electrical then suddenly 1 in electrical and 1 in med bay at the exact same time, that indicates that someone may have vented from electrical to med bay.

When does the admin table update a player's position if they are inside the vent? Does it update when they select another vent to appear out of, or does it update when they pop out of the vent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They appear normal, just like people inside the room regularly. If you see someone teleporting from electrical to medbay or security to electrical or electrical to security or- you get the idea. Look who comes out of security or medbay or electrical and call an emergency to vote them off. I hope you found this answer useful!

Answer (score 1):

Players inside of vents appear on admin. This is useful because you can know when someone is stalking to kill you on admin. If you don't see anyone in the room with you, but admin says there's two people in admin, then someone is hiding in a vent.